# COBOL in Eclipse Luna

Tags: eclipse, cobol

I have downnloaded in Eclipse Luna, Cobol environment. When I press "New Project", COBOL project tab appears.

I am not able to open (or add) a COBOL perspective and I am not able to use the COBOL compiler (I have OpenCOBOL).

So, the question is : how to use this environment (COBOL) in Eclipse LUNA ?

Thank you.

Comment: I can write a file. I can not build it and of course run it.

Comment: Btw, what do you mean by "project looks stale" ?

Comment: OpenCOBOL is now GNU COBOL. Support is available at sourceforge.com. May be a better place for the question.

Comment: The Cobol plugin for Eclipse I was looking at, looked old and unmaintained with a version number 0.13.  That essentially mean "stay far away if you need to use it for real work".  You may be looking at another plugin than me.

Comment: Well ! Finally, has anyone ny idea about how to "convince" eclipse to run COBOL projects ?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The COBOL perspective does not appear as normal.  However when you create a new project the COBOL persona shows in that view.

Click on it and then add a new project.  You will see src and cpy sub directories.  Put the source in the src sub dir and of course cpy sub dir would house any copy book source code.

It does work but it's implementation is not traditional.

Comment: Thanks. What about @Thorbjørn Ravn Andersen's comments?